# How to line numbering for selected text in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]
I want line numbering for this colourful code (like I draw by pen in this image).
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charles Kenyon already correctly mentioned, you will have to work with section breaks if you want line numbering for only a part of your document.

1. Click right in front of `#include`
2. Go to the "Layout" tab
3. Click on "Breaks" and select "Continuous"
4. Click right at the end of the last curly bracket `}` and repeat steps 2-3
5. Click anywhere in your code (in between the 2 section breaks you created) and still in the "Layout" tab click on "Line Numbers" and select "Continuos" or "Restart each Section"

Here is a GIF for clarification. In the GIF, I activated the formatting symbols in the first step, so that we can see the section breaks:

[image]

However, this option might not be ideal in your case, as you will likely have multiple code sections in your document and sections in general make the document more complex. Additionally, the standard line numbers in Word, are outside of the margin.

Therefore, it might be the best that you simply insert the line numbers into the code snippet. You could for example paste your code into Notepad++, [add line numbers there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036307/copy-paste-with-line-number-in-notepad#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20menu%20Edit%2FColumn,Increment%20by%201%20Click%20OK.) and then copy/paste this to Word. Once in Word, you'd simply click right after each number and press the TAB key to create a space between the number and the line of code. Like that, you have the numbers always within your code snippet and they will stay there, even if you change your sections breaks in Word.

Answer (score 0):

### Line numbering, in Word, is a section property.

You will need to insert continuous section breaks before and after the text you want numbered. Then select it and add line numbering for that section on the Layout tab.

Alternatively, you could add a two-column table to your page and have your numbers in one column and your text in the second.

Answer (score 0):

referring to the link mentioned below, does this help?

```
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-line-numbers-b67cd35e-422c-42eb-adc9-256ca9802e22#add
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).